# How to validate email addresses in Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to validate an email field in a table in Access 2010. I tried:

```
Is Null OR ((Like "*?@?*.?*") AND
  (Not Like "*[ ,;]*"))
```

but this did not work.

[image]

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "did not work". I just tried that validation rule (which appears to have come from [here](http://allenbrowne.com/ValidationRule.html)) and it worked for the most common cases. It's not bullet-proof, but I'm sure that it is sufficient for lots of applications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that your database is in `ANSI 92` mode, and when you pasted in the rule...

```
Is Null OR ((Like "*?@?*.?*") AND (Not Like "*[ ,;]*"))
```

...Access automatically changed `Like` to `ALike`, producing...

```
Is Null Or ((ALike "*?@?*.?*") And (Not ALike "*[ ,;]*"))
```

The problem is that `ALike` uses the ANSI wildcard characters, so you need to change the rule to

```
Is Null Or ((ALike "%_@_%._%") And (Not ALike "%[ ,;]%"))
```