# How to validate an email address in MS Access Web App

Tags: ms-access

None of the desktop pattern syntax works for MS Access Web App version.

For example to validate an email in desktop MS Access the formula is explained here:

[How to validate email addresses in Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803858/how-to-validate-email-addresses-in-access)

This does not work in MS Access Web App version.

Comment: The only real way to validate an address is to send an email and require a response.

Comment: Validate basic syntax in an entry box...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj250129.aspx

The Web App version of MS access has a completely different syntax for patterns.

Therefore a pattern for validating an email address is:

```
[FIELDNAME] Is Null Or [FIELDNAME] Like '%@%[^!,@,#,$,%,^,*,&,(,)]%.%[^0-9,!,@,#,$,%,^,*,&,(,)]%'
```

This is at best minimal validation, in that it validates that:

- domain name doesn't contain a limited list of special characters
- registrar doesn't contain numbers or a limited list of special characters

Comment: Bad "shouldn't" vs. "couldn't" google search. Fixed.