# MS Access email validation rule fails

Tags: validation, email, ms-access, email-validation

I have used this rule `((Like "*?@?*.?*") And (Not Like "*[ ,;]*"))` in MS Access for email validation it's working fine, but when I type this `email@youdomain.com@@@hello` it also accepts more **@** signs how to solve this? The rule is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803858/how-to-validate-email-addresses-in-access)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't reliably validate e-mail addresses using an Access SQL statement or regex for that matter, see [this](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) for an example of a regex that still only works on prepared mail addresses, and Access SQL is substantially more limited than regex for text pattern matching.

However, fixing this specific issue is easy:

Just add `Not Like "*@*@*"` to your statement to disallow multiple *@* charactes:

```
((Like "*?@?*.?*") And (Not Like "*[ ,;]*")) And Not Like "*@*@*"
```